# getting current time in different time zone using moment.js

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, momentjs

I am trying to figure out how to get current time in different time zones but below method does not return anything

```
var timeUpdate = setInterval(function () {
    var currentTime = moment().format()
    var GMT_current_time = currentTime.tz("Europe/London").format("HH:mm DD MMM");
$("#GMT_display_time").text(GMT_current_time);  
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The output of the `format` function is a string. The `tz` function works on a moment object.

```
moment().tz("Europe/London")
```

Comment: tried this still did not work,      
var current_time = moment();
var GMT_current_time = current_time.tz("Europe/London").format();

Comment: If you have the moment-timezone script loaded, it should work.  Also, are you actually after GMT? Or are you after London time?  They are not the same thing, as London only follows GMT in the winter.  In the summer, it is on BST.  If you re just after GMT, then you don't need moment-time zone, and can just use the `utc()` function instead.

Comment: thanks, it worked when I loaded the moment timezone script at the end of the body rather than inside the head.

Answer (score 9):

Returns current time with format.

```
moment.tz(moment(), 'Asia/Karachi').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')
```